# c# assembly not referenced for identical code in visual studios?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, assemblies

I am having issues building my 'SharePoint Project' due to an "Xero.Api.Infrastructure.Interface.IAuthenticator is defined in an assembly that is not referenced" Error. The thing is, It was able to correctly build when I used the same code and references in a 'Console Application Project'.

So here is an image of the buildable code:
[Buildable Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INh4O.png)

Here is an image of the non-buildable code: 
[Non-Buildable Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS4jL.png)

Here is the error I get when trying to build my SharePoint Project:
[Referencing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DnkF.png)

The code is:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\public_privatekey.pfx", "lanteria");
var private_app_api = new XeroCoreApi("https://api.xero.com", new PrivateAuthenticator(cert),
                new Consumer("GPR4Vxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6TRVCI", "0VMT6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxRD26S"), null,
                new DefaultMapper(), new DefaultMapper());
```

The error occurs when trying to use PrivateAuthenticator object as the input when it takes an IAuthenticator object. The PrivateAuthenticator object is a subclass of IAuthenticator so this should not be an issue.

I have made sure that I have referenced the assemblies the same way in both projects. I even did it a third time to make sure of this. The only difference is that one project is a Console Application project and the other Project is a SharePoint project. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `X is defined in an assembly that is not referenced` you managed to leave out the important part, and paste images of your code and errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need download the nuget

```
 PM> Install-Package Xero.API.SDK.Minimal or Install-Package Xero.API.SDK
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Maybe its because of the way I signed my dll files? 

This is the code I used to sign them:


`ildasm /all /out=Xero.Api.Example.Applications.il Xero.Api.Example.Applications.dll`

`ildasm /all /out=Xero.Api.il Xero.Api.dll`

`sn -k mykey.snk`

`ilasm /dll /key=mykey.snk Xero.Api.Example.Applications.il`

`ilasm /dll /key=mykey.snk Xero.Api.il`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the root of the issue but still have been unable to solve it. I am currently using a workaround. The issue was that one of my assemblies was referencing the other and for some reason in SharePoint project, it is unable to.
i.e.

- SharePoint Project references A & B
- A is an independent assembly
- B references A.

The problem is that for some reason B is unable to reference A. My temporary workaround is that since I was able to run on ConsoleApplication, I had my SharePoint project run the console application. This enables me to create triggers on SharePoint that will run the console application which will push changes to Xero.